# Purpose of Uniqueness Proofs

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

What is the purpose of uniqueness? Or more specifically what is lost without uniqueness?

In probability class we have been going over measures. The professor went out of his way to prove that the measure not only existed, but was also unique. I understand why we would need existence, but I don't understand why go through the time to prove uniqueness. Regardless, if we could prove that a measure or some mathematical structure isn't unique what can we conclude/what would we lose?

It seems to me that we would search for the rest of the solutions if the mathematical structure wasn't unique.

Comment: I think my position being uniquely where I am right now and not possibly also at the core of our planet is something that I like a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is being proved is unique. If you are proving that the measure of a set is unique, then that's required for it to be a useful and well defined quantity. If measures of sets aren't unique, then why use them? You (usually) can't do much meaningful math if $2=\mu(S)=3$

Comment: So when we prove uniqueness for measures we are proving the value of the measure of each set is unique. Thank you this helped a lot!